# Azure Ethereum(PoW) Blockchain issues

Tags: azure, blockchain, ethereum, web3js, azure-blockchain-service

I'm trying to run Ethereum Blockchain network with Azure Blockchain Service but I stuck with some issues.... And below I described one of them.

I will realy apreciate any advice and help from people who alredy has experience with Azure Blockchain Service.

Could you please help me to eliminate this error:

"Error: Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks"

I create new Ethereum blockchain network and it's working fine approximately 1 day (24 hours) but after this period I'm not able to deploy my smart-contract and getting this error. When I restart my virtual machines (mining and transaction nodes) it's start working for a while but later on it's failing again.

1. What could be the cause of this error: "Error: Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks"? I tried increasing gasPrice but it didn't help.
2. What the recomended server hardware configuration for mining and transaction nodes to run Azure Ethereum Blockchain Service? Maybe my virtual machines run out of the RAM or SSD?
3. Also could you tell me please where can I see some error log related to my blockchain network in Azure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this GitHub issue detailed in the Truffle Suite (issue) repository. The issue you are experiencing is cause by Truffle Suite, and can be quickly explained as:

> ... now believe this may be caused by Infura closing the connection while truffle-hdwallet-provider continues to try to poll them.

[Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/926)
[using infura in truffle and get Error: Invalid JSON RPC response:""](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/852)

Investigating...